# Symfony function render parameters dynamique

Tags: php, symfony, twig, render

Hello everybody I come towards you because I have small one concerns and I hope that to go to be able to you help me, I to create a shop with symfony but I have a small problem with the function "render ()" when I makes cross id in the controller kind by putting 3 or 4 for example it works but when I puts him dynamically that does not work

i share my code
my controller

```
 /**
     * @Route("/produits-views/{id}", name="product-views", methods="GET")
     * @param int $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function viewsProduct(int $id): Response {

        $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Product::class)->find($id);

        return $this->render('inc/views-product.html.twig', [
            'productViews' => $product
        ]);
    }
```

and my function render

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\FrontController::viewsProduct',
    {id: productViews.id}
)) }}
```

i include this on footer.html.twig and footer is include in base.html.twig

He takes out to me a message of this type

```
Variable "productViews" does not exist.
```

thank you for you helps !

Comment: In template what do you get when you dump that variable.?

Comment: Well it does not work because you have to pass a paramet 
when I do {id: 3} it works but when I do {id: id}
he tells me he does not find the variable

Comment: Look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html probably you need to build a global Twig variable to make it available for all templates.

Answer (score 0):

change your action to let Symfony takes care of the fetching process:

```
/**
 * @Route("/produits-views/{id}", name="product-views", methods="GET")
 * @param Product $product
 * @return Response
 */
public function viewsProductAction(Product $product): Response {
    return $this->render('inc/views-product.html.twig', [
        'productViews' => $product
    ]);
}
```

calling render with productViews.id in base.twig requires that in every view that extends this template need to have the productViews variable accessible which means that it have been provided to the view with render parameters.

you need to think about it, does all the views you have provide this variable like a user in the session if not remove it, you can alter the footer content from the view if you need to show the product according to each view using a dedicated Block for footer.

Comment: it does not work but I think it's not really a problem of symfony but rather a problem JS seen that it is a modal window

Comment: this class: "js-show-modal1" it is connected to the model , how to manage it in javascript? you have an idea ?

Comment: no its not JS, you should know that {{productViews}} will be known only after you render your view "viewsProduct" and only inside its twig not before and not outside which means that "footer.twig" or "base.twig" cant access this variable unless you provided it in the current action (not viewsProductAction)

Comment: The variable product Views does not recognize her yet